# Setting AWS S3 Storage Class for AWS Media Convert Outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-media-convert

Is there a way to set the storage class of output files of an AWS MediaConvert job? For example, if I convert a video to HLS format and store it in a S3 bucket, can I set the default storage class as Intelligent Tiering? Currently, all outputs are by default set to the 'Standard' storage class.